# Efficient solutuon to Filter objects inside objects inside an array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects containing more objects.

```
const latestMatchesArray = [
    {
      team1: {
        team_id: '1234',
        teamName: 'abc 101',
        score: 1,
      },
      team2: {
        team_id: '4321',
        teamName: 'cba 101',
        score: 0,
      },
    },
    {
      team1: {
        team_id: '1234',
        teamName: 'abc 101',
        score: 0,
      },
      team2: {
        team_id: '4321',
        teamName: 'cba 101',
        score: 1,
      },
    },
  ]
```

Each object contains a match between two teams, after the match, the scores are updated.
Winner gets 1, loser gets 0.

Now I want to filter the array and get only teams with score = 1.

How to do this efficiently?

Comment: If you have an array containing matches, and you filter it, you get an array with fewer matches, not an array of teams. How do you want to collect teams?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but to get an array of teams that won, you can use `Array.prototype.reduce()` like this:

```js
const winners = latestMatchesArray.reduce(
    (teams, match) => [
        ...teams,
        ...[match.team1, match.team2].filter(
            team => team.score === 1
        )
    ],
    []
);
```